# Getting the ClaimsPrincipal in a separated project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

I'm writing an aspnet core 2.0 application. Using a bearer token authentication I have the `User` property inside the controller with the correct identity. How can I access the `User` property or the `ClaimPrincipal` in the separated .net standard project for business logic?

ASP.NET Core project:

```
//ASP.NET Core project
public class DocumentController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal cp = User;

        /* check for claims in ClaimsPrincipal */

        DocumentBL docBL = new DocumentBL();
        docBL.BLmethodForDocument();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Separated .net standard project: BL.dll

My ASP.NET Core project depends on BL.dll

```
//Separated project: BL.dll
public class DocumentBL
{
    public void BLmethodForDocument()
    {
        System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal cp = ???????????

        /* check for claims in ClaimsPrincipal */

        //rest of business logic...
    }
}
```

How can I fix the BLmethodForDocument to work with current `ClaimsPrincipal` WITHOUT passing it to the bl method as parameter (and WITHOUT passing it to the DocumentBL constructor)?

Can not use `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current` nor `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` they are always null.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.User

Comment: I would rather suggest passing the User as a parameter to the Method in BL project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291374/getting-the-claimsprincipal-in-a-logic-layer-in-an-aspnet-core-1-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ClaimsPrincipal in a logic layer in an aspnet core 1 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291374/getting-the-claimsprincipal-in-a-logic-layer-in-an-aspnet-core-1-application)

Comment: @Kalyan it is not the same, because when I set `services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipal>(s => s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);` to the Startup.cs in my ASP.NET Core project, I still can not access the current ClaimPrincipal in separated business logic project.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya `HttpContext.Current.Request.User` does not exists. I think you means `HttpContext.Current.User` but in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.Current.User` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` assembly does not exists the `public static HttpContext Current { get; set; }` property like in .NET v4.7 and earlier .NET Framewrok versions...

Comment: You need to embrace dependency injection. In your business layer too. Make dependencies explicit in your business layer, and you no longer need to ask yourself how to get some dependency within a method.

Comment: @poke thank you, you helped me. The solution is add my `DocumentBL` to Startup.cs `ConfigureServices`: `services.AddTransient<DocumentBL>();` and `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` and `services.AddTransient<ClaimsPrincipal>(s => s.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);`