# Accessing Claims Principal in the Service layer in the API of a Net core 6 App

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, claims-based-identity

I need to access `ClaimsPrincipal` within the service layer of a Net Core 6 app.

I could always just `builder.Services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` in the `Startup.cs` & go my merry way but this is a no-no. Makes it difficult to test and more importantly this is a great example of *leaky* abstraction.

So, now what I have is the following

```
  public class ClaimsProvider : IClaimsProvider
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public ClaimsProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)  
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public ClaimsPrincipal? GetClaimsPrincipal()
        {
            return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
        }
    }

    public interface IClaimsProvider
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal? GetClaimsPrincipal();
    }
```

Within my `Startup.cs` `AddScoped()` that takes an IHttpContextAccessor and return an IClaimsProvider. Then I simply build all services against IClaimsProvider

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IClaimsProvider>(provider =>
{
    var httpContextAccessor = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    return new ClaimsProvider(httpContextAccessor);
});
```

And the usual route for my services where I inject it as a dependency

```
      private readonly IClaimsProvider _claimsProvider;
        public SomeService(
            IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
            IMapper mapper, IClaimsProvider claimsProvider, ...)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment ?? 
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostingEnvironment));
            _mapper = mapper ?? 
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
            _claimsProvider = claimsProvider;
        }   

        public void SomeMethod() 
        {
            var u = _claimsProvider.GetClaimsPrincipal();
            foreach (var claim in u.Claims)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type} : {claim.Value}");
            }

        }
```

My question is that is the above approach ok? Potentially, is there any other approach that is better than the one shown above?

Comment: I've accessed the `HttpContext` directly from a `Controller` as described with many other scenarios [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0) .

Comment: @davmos I'm not accessing the ClaimsPrincipal from the controller, I need it in the business layer. Using bearer token authentication, I have the user object i.e. ClaimsPrincipal in the controller but that is not "automatically" available below in the business layer. That's the reason I have to jump through these hoops and the question was is there a better way of doing this or is what I have shown in my question good enough. The `HttpContext` is not available in the service layer unless one uses `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` but then this is a _leaky_ abstraction as stated in my ques

Comment: What type of project is the service/business layer and what other types of project are in the app & how do they all communicate?

Comment: @davmos service/business layer is a regular  Net Core 6 API (standard ApiContoller, business layer, data layer). Behind `Identity 4` and returns `json` which can be consumed by any type of client. So right now we have a React app as well as a MVC app. Though not sure what that has to do with accessing `ClaimsPrincipal` in the business layer.

Comment: Another cheap approach is to pass your principal into service as methods argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent a leaky abstract (the need for an `IHttpContextAsccessor` in your service), I would recommend using the [Adapter Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  services.AddScoped<IClaimsProvider, HttpContextClaimsProvider>();
}
 
public IClaimsProvider
{
  public ClaimsPrinciple ClaimsPrinciple { get; }
}
 
// Adapter
public HttpContextClaimsProvider : IClaimsProvider
{
  public HttpContextClaimsProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
  {
    ClaimsProvider = httpContext?.User?.Principle as ClaimsPrinciple;
  }
  public ClaimsPrinciple ClaimsPrinciple { get; private set; }
 
}
 
 
public class YourService : IYourService 
{
  private readonly IClaimsProvider _claimsProvider;
 
  public YourService(IClaimsProvider claimsProvider)
  {
    _claimsProvider= claimsProvider;
  }
}
```

Comment: How's that different from what OP describes in their question?

Comment: Also, what's ClaimsPrinciple?

Comment: @WiktorZychla [ClaimsPrinciple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Hows it different?  It uses the Adapter pattern...

Comment: It's `ClaimsPrincipal` obviously

Comment: As for the Adapter, in both cases, you and the OP, get the `IHttpContextAccessor` as the provider's constructor argument. In both cases you register the provider in the container. In both cases you then inject the provider in a concrete service. I'm asking about an explanation for the community, so that everyone seeking for advice and bumping into your answer, would have a clear understanding on how and why it's relevant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm not sure what else there is to understand as the service does not require an `IHttpContextAccessor`.  If the service is no longer used with an HttpContext, someone would just write a new `IClaimsProvider` to provide the claims how ever they need to be passed, but the service itself doesn't need to be changed nor does it referece any *Http* specific dependencies.

Comment: I understand perfectly your solution and I hope everyone else does too. My request to you was not about explaining your approach but but explaining the difference between your approach and OP example code in their question. You said "it uses the adapter pattern". But theirs also does as it's basically the same code. And, could you please edit your code to correct `ClaimsPrinciple` (incorrect, wouldn't even compile) to `ClaimsPrincipal` (correct)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In our design each controller action receives an `FooRequest`. This is a POCO object where the properties are filled from the model binder by using corresponding attributes:

```
public class FooRequest : RequestBase
{
    [FromRoute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [FromQuery]
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public SomeComplexObject Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally we made a derived class using the suffix `WithUser` that has a ClaimsPrincipal as additional property:

```
public class FooRequestWithUser : FooRequest, IRequest<FooResponse>
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; set; }
}
```

In a next step we made a helper class that provides a helper method that can receive the request instance, a claims principal and a type T:

```
public class RequestBase
{
    public T Of<T>(ClaimsPrincipal user) where T: class, new()
    {
        // Check if T has base of own type
        // Create instance and iterate all props to get value
        // from this and and set value in instance.
        // Additionally use reflection to set user property.
    }
}
```

When our normal request class is derived from this one, we can call it within our controller and create a model containing the user as an additional property and forward it into our services by using MediatR:

```
public IActionResult DoFoo(FooRequest request)
{
    var requestWithUser = request.Of<FooRequestWithUser>(User);
    var result = mediator.Send(requestWithUser);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

By this approach the claims principal is bound to the request consumed by the service and not something it has to additionally receive. Also it makes clear, that this request must be somehow authenticated and the service should check for some potential permissions or similar.

Comment: in our apps, by the time the request is at the service layer, the middleware has already ensured that the user is authenticated & is authorized via ABAC attribute based access control (https://www.okta.com/blog/2020/09/attribute-based-access-control-abac/) before the controller is called. All that the services usually have to do is extract the subject claim or say the email claim to query the dB and/or call some other remote service in so far as the `ClaimsPrincipal` is concerned.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of making [God Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) as they break the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: @ErikPhilips IMHO this isn't a God Object. It really depends on the definition, what belongs together. In our approach we defined, that information about the user belongs to the request itself and should be forwareded bundled through the system.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal: We already use middleware to authenticate the user. Also a base RBAC check is done in the middleware by using attributes, but in a multi-tenant app additional checks must be on a per tenant basis. This is done down in the service (by calling other specialized services). This works very well and allows some further performance improvements in lookups, but is really to complex to explain in a comment. 

Comment: What is the advantage of this approach over the accepted answer?

Comment: @MrDave1999 There is no _advantage_ or _better_. It's just another approach where the user is bound to the request object and not available through another service. IMHO makes it easier to declare if the requesting user is _needed_ for the given request on the controller level instead of the service level.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you have described is generally considered a valid way to access the ClaimsPrincipal in the service layer of a .NET Core 6 app, as it abstracts the implementation details of the IHttpContextAccessor, making it easier to test and maintain.

An alternative approach could be to use the built-in dependency injection in ASP.NET Core to directly inject the ClaimsPrincipal into the service, without the need for a separate IClaimsProvider interface.

You can do this by registering the ClaimsPrincipal as a service in the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class.

Comment: Actually, that's correct and that's possibly the simplest possible approach using injection. You don't even have to register anything as a service, just let `ClaimsPrincipal` be automatically injected into the service as an argument.